# Deform/bend non-planar object over a surface

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap

First off, I'm pretty new to blender, so I apologise if this is a basic problem/question.

I'm trying to create detail on a surface, and the most obvious way I can think of is to create a half cylinder and shrinkwrap it onto the surface. But I guess this only really works for planar type objects?

What's happening is that the cylinder is following the target surface properly, but it's totally squished flat onto the surface. I want to preserve the cylinder as it wraps over the surface.

Here's what I'm trying to do, I hope it explains it better than I can describe.

**Target Object Surface:**
[image: Target]

**The effect of the Shrink Wrap:**
[image: Shrink]

**What I'm trying to emulate:**
[image: Emulate]

So the question is, is there a way to get shrinkwrap to do what I want, or is there a better way altogether?

Comment: Please use stackexchange built-in image adding tools instead of using external links.

Comment: do you mean that you want to bend a pipe? maybe use a Curve modifier?

Comment: @moonboots not the pipe, but the ribs on the muffler. Sorry, the first image I chose wasn't great

Comment: don't create a new object, create edge loops on your object and extrude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating a new object, you could use your current object, create some edge loops:

[image]

Bevel them:

[image]

Only keep a part selected:

[image]

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to *Extrude Faces Along Normals*:

[image]

Here is what it gives when you give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier (put additional edge loops if you want to sharpen the edges):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that will do exactly what I need